# Node.js ffmpeg download M3U8 URL as MP4

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I've installed **ffmpeg.js** using **Node.js**.

I want to be able to give an URL as an argument (where the resource located at the URL is an M3U8 file), and download it as an MP4.

With regular command line ffmpeg (not JavaScript ported), the command would be the following:

```
ffmpeg -i http://example.com/file.m3u8 -c copy out.mp4
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
var ffmpeg = require("ffmpeg.js");
var fs = require("fs");

var result = ffmpeg({
  arguments: ["-i", "http://example.com/file.m3u8", "-c", "copy", "out.mp4"],
});

fs.writeFileSync("out.mp4", Buffer(result));
```

Comment: Show the full console output for the PHP ffmpeg execution.

Comment: http://example.com/file.m3u8: Protocol not found.  
undefined.e.printErr.e.printErr @ bundle.js:21592